# Trial pre-registration service that accepts non-clinical trials, or specifically ecology?

Tags: ecology

I'm in the early stages of designing a trial in ecology. I'm interested in pre-registering the trial, as suggested [here](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fevo.2014.00076/full).

My concern is that all of the registries (that I can find) deal specifically with clinical trials, not ecological or general natural-sciences research. Does anyone know of a service that would accept pre-registration of non-clinical biological trials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try OSF.io?

They offer a free service where you can preregister trials and give them a timestamp with a DOI number etc.

I do not know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but it's the easiest solution for preregistering and I am quite sure that it would be enough to get the "preregistration" badge when you are finally ready to publish.

[Here is more info on how to do it and what is essential for preregistration.](https://osf.io/47uq9/)

Comment: It looks like the 'Registrations' feature of OSF should satisfy a reasonable journal-editor that a study has been pre-registered. Answer accepted.

Comment: An addition to that - it seems that OSF plans to offer a "financial reward" for pre-registration, see https://osf.io/x5w7h/